# Immutable queue in Clojure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, clojure, queue, immutability

What is the best way to obtain a simple, efficient immutable queue data type in Clojure?

It only needs two operations, enqueue and dequeue with the usual semantics.

I considered lists and vectors of course, but I understand that they have comparatively poor performance  (i.e. O(n) or worse) for modifications at the end and beginning respectively - so not ideal for queues!

Ideally I'd like a proper persistent data structure with O(log n) for both enqueue and dequeue operations.

Comment: To save someone from writing about how cons lists can be used to implement push/pop stacks (like I almost did), don't forget the question asks about *queues*. :-)

Comment: Just noticed there is a class called PersistentQueue in the latest 1.2 snapshot Clojure Java source.... may be the answer to my own question

Comment: It's been in there since forever (just checked with 1.1, but I think it's older than that). Note that there's no factory function nor reader syntax for it provided by default; use `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY` to get an empty instance. Then `conj`, `pop` & `peek` work as they should with a queue. See e.g. my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760017 for some code written with both `c.l.PQ` and Java's `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: Cool, thanks Michal! I guess I missed it at first because there wasn't a simple "queue" constructor in the API. Maybe I should submit a patch :-)

Comment: `PersistentQueue` is indeed one of Clojure's more closely guarded secrets. ;-) About possible queue-related API enhancements, see this thread on Clojure Dev: http://groups.google.com/group/clojure-dev/browse_thread/thread/e0fad47532028e99 Note that's probably a very low-priority matter right now, what with the new numerics and all...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Problem solved - solution for others who may find it helpful.

I've found that Clojure has the clojure.lang.PersistentQueue class that does what is needed.

You can create an instance like this:

```
(def x (atom clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY))
```

As far as I can see, you currently need to use the Java interop to create the instance but as Michal helpfully pointed out you can use peek, pop and conj subsequently.

Comment: PersistentQueue is indeed your best option. For future reference, here is a table summarizing the performance characteristics/guarantees of clojure data structures: http://www.innoq.com/blog/st/2010/04/clojure_performance_guarantees.html

Comment: @raxod502 Is there something wrong with the use of an atom in this situation?

Comment: @dgellow From my understanding, using atoms in functional programming languages is a Bad Sign unless there's a good reason for it -- everything is generally supposed to be immutable.

Comment: @RadonRosborough, ...however, it's definitely better practice to have an atom inside a Var than to mutate the Var itself. Which is to say, *if* you're going to use `def` (which isn't always necessary, granted!) to put a name to something other than a constant, then an appropriately-chosen reference type is typically the right thing to associate with it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're certainly right. The only reason I commented was because there was nothing in the question that suggested STM or mutable state was desired, so I found it very odd that the answer used an `atom` for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 9):

I use the following function `queue` to create a PersistentQueue.  Optionally, you might want to have a print-method and a data-reader if you're going to be printing and reading the queues.

The usual Clojure functions are already implemented for PersistentQueue.

- peek -- get the head
- pop -- returns a new PersistentQueue without the head
- conj -- add item to the tail
- empty? -- true if empty
- seq -- contents as a sequence (list)

```
    (defn queue
      ([] clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)
      ([coll] (reduce conj clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY coll)))

    (defmethod print-method clojure.lang.PersistentQueue
      [q ^java.io.Writer w]
      (.write w "#queue ")
      (print-method (sequence q) w))

    (comment
       (let [*data-readers* {'queue #'queue}]
         (read-string (pr-str (queue [1 2 3])))))
```

Comment: At least in Clojure 1.11, there's already some sort of print method: `(queue [1 2 3 4])  => <-(1 2 3 4)-<` where `=>` is the output indicator and the rest is the output. No such luck trying to `read-string` it though...

Comment: Nevermind, just my noobness showing through. `print-method` is used when you pass the queue to something like `println`, not when you evaluate the queue in the REPL. In Clojure 1.11 this is still required.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure could really benefit from a queue literal. This would be cleaner (and more portable) than relying on Java interop.

However, it's not that hard to roll your own portable persistent queue, just using ordinary household items like lists.

Consider the queue as two lists, one providing the head portion of the queue, and the other the tail. `enqueue` adds to the first list, `dequeue` pops from the latter. Most `ISeq` functions are trivially implemented.

Probably the only tricky part is what happens when the tail is empty and you want to `dequeue`. In that case the head list is `reverse`d and becomes the new tail, and the empty list becomes the new head list. I believe, even with the overhead of the `reverse`, that `enqueue` and `dequeue` remain `O(1)`, though the `k` is going to be higher than a vanilla vector of course.

Happy `queue`ing!