# Clojure Producer Consumer

Tags: clojure

I am learning clojure and try out its concurrency and effectiveness via a producer consumer example.

Did that and it felt pretty akward with having to use ref and deref and also watch and unwatch.

I tried to check other code snippet; but is there a better way of re factoring this other than using Java Condition await() and signal() methods along with Java Lock. I did not want to use anything in Java.

here is the code; i guess I would have made many mistakes here with my usage...

```
;a simple producer class
(ns my.clojure.producer
    (:use  my.clojure.consumer)
  (:gen-class)
  )

 (def tasklist( ref (list) )) ;this is declared as a global variable; to make this 
    ;mutable we need to use the fn ref


(defn gettasklist[]
    (deref tasklist) ;we need to use deref fn to return the task list
  )

(def testagent (agent 0)); create an agent


(defn emptytasklist[akey aref old-val new-val]

   (doseq [item (gettasklist)]
        (println(str "item is") item)
        (send testagent consume item)
        (send testagent increment item)
     )
      (. java.lang.Thread sleep 1000)
   (dosync ; adding a transaction for this is needed to reset

      (remove-watch tasklist "key123"); removing the watch on the tasklist so that it does not
                                       ; go to a recursive call
      (ref-set tasklist (list ) ) ; we need to make it as a ref to reassign
      (println (str "The number of tasks now remaining is=")  (count (gettasklist)))

     )
  (add-watch tasklist "key123" emptytasklist)
 )
(add-watch tasklist "key123" emptytasklist)

  (defn addtask [task] 
    (dosync ; adding a transaction for this is needed to refset
      ;(println (str "The number of tasks before") (count (gettasklist)))
      (println (str "Adding a task") task)
      (ref-set tasklist (conj (gettasklist) task )) ; we need to make it as a ref to reassign
      ;(println (str "The number of tasks after") (count (gettasklist)))
     )
  )
```

Here is the consumer code

```
(ns my.clojure.consumer
  )
(defn consume[c item]

  (println  "In the consume method:Item is " c item  )
  item 
)
(defn increment [c n] 
  (println "parmeters are" c n)
  (+ c n)
  )
```

And here is the test code ( I have used maven to run clojure code and used NetBeans to edit as this is more familiar to me coming from Java  - folder structure and pom at - https://github.com/alexcpn/clojure-evolve

```
(ns my.clojure.Testproducer
        (:use my.clojure.producer)
        (:use clojure.test)
      (:gen-class)
  )

(deftest test-addandcheck

  (addtask 1)
  (addtask 2)
  (is(= 0 (count (gettasklist))))
   (println (str "The number of tasks are") (count (gettasklist)))

 )
```

If anybody can refactor this lightly so that I can read and understand the code then it will be great; Else I guess I will have to learn more

**Edit -1**

I guess using a global task list and making it available to other functions by de-referencing it (deref) and again making it mutable by ref is not the way in clojure;

So changing the addTask method to directly send the incoming tasks to an agent

```
(defn addtask [task] 
    (dosync ; adding a transaction for this is needed to refset

      (println (str "Adding a task") task)

        ;(ref-set tasklist (conj (gettasklist) task )) ; we need to make it as a ref to reassign
       (def testagent (agent 0)); create an agent
       (send testagent consume task)
       (send testagent increment task)

     )
```

However when I tested it

```
(deftest test-addandcheck
  (loop [task 0]
    (when ( < task 100)
        (addtask task)
      (recur (inc task))))

  (is(= 0 (count (gettasklist))))
   (println (str "The number of tasks are") (count (gettasklist)))

 )
```

after sometime the I am getting Java rejected execution exception -- This is fine if you do Java threads, because you take full control. But from clojure this looks odd, especially since you are not selecting the ThreadPool stratergy  yourself

```
Adding a task 85
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-4" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionExce
ption
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1759)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.jav
a:767)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.ja
va:658)
        at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.execute(Agent.java:56)
        at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.doRun(Agent.java:95)
        at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.run(Agent.java:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:885)Adding a task 86
Adding a task 87
```

Answer (score 4):

I think modeling producer & consumer in clojure would be done the easiest (and most efficiently) using [lamina channels](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina/wiki/Channels).

Comment: Thanks,I am sure this is the best way, but I don't want to use any libraries now since I am learning

Comment: I guess using a global task list and making it available to other functions by de-referencing it (deref) and again making it mutable by ref is not the way in clojure;

Answer (score 1):

I have made similar clojure program with producer/consumer pattern in [Computing Folder Sizes Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871493/computing-folder-size).

I don't think that you really need to use Refs.
You have single tasklist that is mutable state that you want to *alter synchronously*. Changes are relatively quick and do not depend on any other external state, only the variable that comes in to consumer.

As far with atoms there is **swap!** function which can help you do the changes the way I understood you need.

You can look at my snippet [Computing folder size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871493/computing-folder-size/5882434) i think it can at least show you proper use of atoms & agents. I played with it a lot, so it should be correct.

Hope it helps!

Regards, 
Jan

Comment: The tasklist can be altered by any number of producer threads at any time.

Comment: That's correct, it's the way you access the mutable state - that is important. Remember you have **one shared state**.

Atoms work wonderfully when you want to insure atomic updates to an individual piece of state. _I do not see that you are coordinating any updates._

The producer produces data, and consumer consumes data from the common shared state.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the Clojure examples for Twitter storm. He just used [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). It's easy to use, concurrent and performs well. Sure, it lacks the sex-appeal of an immutable Clojure solution, but it will work well.

Comment: I have done multi threaded programs in Java using BlockingQueue Future Task ets. And it is easy and efficient. Clojure for multi threading for me as a clojure amateaur dont appeal much, if I have to write so much ugly code for a producer-consumer, with so much ref and deref

Answer (score 0):

I've come across several use cases where I need the ability to:

- strictly control the number of worker threads on both the producer and consumer side
- control the maximum size of the "work queue" in order to limit memory consumption
- detect when all work has been completed so that I can shut down the workers

I've found that the clojure built-in concurrency features (while amazingly simple and useful in their own right) make the first two bullet points difficult.  `lamina` looks great, but I didn't see a way that it would address my particular use cases w/o the same sort of extra plumbing that I'd need to do around an implementation based on `BlockingQueue`.

So, I ended up hacking together a simple clojure library to try to solve my problems.  It is basically just a wrapper around `BlockingQueue` that attempts to conceal some of the Java constructs and provide a higher-level producer-consumer API.  I'm not entirely satisfied with the API yet; it'll likely evolve a bit further... but it's operational:

https://github.com/cprice-puppet/freemarket

Example usage:

```
(def myproducer (producer producer-work-fn num-workers max-work))
(def myconsumer (consumer myproducer consumer-work-fn num-workers max-results))
(doseq [result (work-queue->seq (:result-queue myconsumer))]
  (println result))
```

Feedback / suggestions / contributions would be welcomed!