# Producer Consumer Queue in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to build a producer-consumer program in clojure. The requirement is the consumer can drag items from the queue while the producer is putting messages into the queue, if using java I will use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, but I'm not very sure how to do it in clojure using the immutable collections, please help.

Comment: Do you know about [clojure.lang.PersistentQueue](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentQueue.java)?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler I'd expect to use pure clojure code like vector, list, ref kind of things to implement this, just dont know if it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want 1 consumer, just use an agent. If not see
see [Clojure Producer Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925371/clojure-producer-consumer) or [Producer consumer with qualifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760017/producer-consumer-with-qualifications)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use Clojure's [immutable queue](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/seque) inside of an atom, which would give you atomic access to the queue.