# Work queues in Clojure

Tags: clojure, queue

I’m using a Clojure application to access data from a web API. I’m going to be making a lot of requests, and many of the requests will lead to more requests being made, so I want to keep the request URLs in a queue that will leave 60 seconds between subsequent downloads.

Following [this blog post](http://blog.marrowboy.co.uk/2011/10/21/worker-queues-in-clojure/) I put this together:

```lisp
(def queue-delay (* 1000 60)) ; one minute

(defn offer!
  [q x]
  (.offerLast q x)
  q)

(defn take!
  [q]
  (.takeFirst q))

(def my-queue (java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.))

(defn- process-queue-item
  [item]
  (println ">> " item)   ; this would be replaced by downloading `item`
  (Thread/sleep queue-delay))
```

If I include a `(future (process-queue-item (take! my-queue)))` in my code somewhere then at the REPL I can `(offer! my-queue "something")` and I see the ">> something" printed immediately. So far so good! But I need the queue to last for the entire time my program is active. The `(future ...)` call I just mentioned works to pull one item out of the queue, once it’s available, but I want something that will watch the queue continually and call `process-queue-item` whenever something is available.

Also, contrary to the usual Clojure love for concurrency, I want to ensure that only one request is being made at a time and that my program waits 60 seconds to make each subsequent request.

I think [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760017/producer-consumer-with-qualifications) is relevant, but I’m not sure how to adapt it to do what I want. How do I poll my queue continuously and ensure that only one request is being run at once?

Comment: Why do you want to poll continuously but only send every 60 seconds?  Would polling just once every 60 seconds accomplish the same thing?

Comment: @mamboking Almost, yes. The only downside of that approach would be adding the first item to the queue: if it takes the program five seconds to figure out what the first request URL will be then it will just sit there for 55 seconds until the queue is checked. The program will be pretty long-running anyway though so I guess that’s not too much of an issue.

Comment: are you avoiding a task scheduler? For example, this one, https://github.com/zcaudate/cronj (there's also a list of other libraries in that repo's readme)

Comment: @georgek I’m not necessarily avoiding something like that, although it does seem like overkill for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own small library, which I called [simple-queue](https://github.com/bdesham/simple-queue). You can read the full documentation on GitHub, but here is the source in its entirety. **I’m not going to keep this answer updated, so if you’d like to use this library please get the source from GitHub.**

```lisp
(ns com.github.bdesham.simple-queue)

(defn new-queue
  "Creates a new queue. Each trigger from the timer will cause the function f
  to be invoked with the next item from the queue. The queue begins processing
  immediately, which in practice means that the first item to be added to the
  queue is processed immediately."
  [f & opts]
  (let [options (into {:delaytime 1}
                      (select-keys (apply hash-map opts) [:delaytime])),
        delaytime (:delaytime options),
        queue {:queue (java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.)},
        task (proxy [java.util.TimerTask] []
               (run []
                 (let [item (.takeFirst (:queue queue)),
                       value (:value item),
                       prom (:promise item)]
                   (if prom
                     (deliver prom (f value))
                     (f value))))),
        timer (java.util.Timer.)]
    (.schedule timer task 0 (int (* 1000 delaytime)))
    (assoc queue :timer timer)))

(defn cancel
  "Permanently stops execution of the queue. If a task is already executing
  then it proceeds unharmed."
  [queue]
  (.cancel (:timer queue)))

(defn process
  "Adds an item to the queue, blocking until it has been processed. Returns
  (f item)."
  [queue item]
  (let [prom (promise)]
    (.offerLast (:queue queue)
                {:value item,
                 :promise prom})
    @prom))

(defn add
  "Adds an item to the queue and returns immediately. The value of (f item) is
  discarded, so presumably f has side effects if you're using this."
  [queue item]
  (.offerLast (:queue queue)
              {:value item,
               :promise nil}))
```

An example of using this queue to return values:

```lisp
(def url-queue (q/new-queue slurp :delaytime 30))
(def github (q/process url-queue "https://github.com"))
(def google (q/process url-queue "http://www.google.com"))
```

The calls to `q/process` will block so that there will be a 30-second delay between the two `def` statements.

An example of using this queue purely for side effects:

```lisp
(defn cache-url
  [{url :url, filename :filename}]
  (spit (java.io.File. filename)
        (slurp url)))

(def url-queue (q/new-queue cache-url :delaytime 30))
(q/add url-queue {:url "https://github.com",
                  :filename "github.html"})    ; returns immediately
(q/add url-queue {:url "https://google.com",
                  :filename "google.html"})    ; returns immediately
```

Now the calls to `q/add` return immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code snippet from [a project I did for fun](https://github.com/jeremyheiler/trabajo/blob/master/src/trabajo/core.clj#L98). It's not perfect, but can give you an idea of how I got around the "wait 55 seconds for the first item" problem. It basically cycles through promises, using futures to process things immediately or until a promise "becomes" available.

```
(defn ^:private process
  [queues]
  (loop [[q & qs :as q+qs] queues p (atom true)]
    (when-not (Thread/interrupted)
      (if (or
            (< (count (:promises @work-manager)) (:max-workers @work-manager))
            @p) ; blocks until a worker is available
        (if-let [job (dequeue q)]
          (let [f (future-call #(process-job job))]
            (recur queues (request-promise-from-work-manager)))
          (do
            (Thread/sleep 5000)
            (recur (if (nil? qs) queues qs) p)))
        (recur q+qs (request-promise-from-work-manager))))))
```

Maybe you could do something similar? The code isn't great, and could probably take be re-written to use `lazy-seq`, but that's just an exercise I haven't gotten to yet!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite possibly insane but you could always use a function like this to create a slowed-down lazy sequence:

```
(defn slow-seq [delay-ms coll]
  "Creates a lazy sequence with delays between each element"
  (lazy-seq 
    (if-let [s (seq coll)]
        (do 
          (Thread/sleep delay-ms)
          (cons (first s)
                (slow-seq delay-ms (rest s)))))))
```

This will basically ensure a delay between each of the function invocations.

You can use it with something like the following, providing a delay in milliseconds:

```
(doseq [i (slow-seq 500 (range 10))]
  (println (rand-int 10))
```

Or alternatively you can put your function call inside the sequence with something like:

```
(take 10 (slow-seq 500 (repeatedly #(rand-int 10))))
```

Obviously, in both of the above you can replace `(rand-int 10)` with whatever code you are using to perform/trigger a download.

Comment: If I’m reading this right, all of the elements of `coll` would have to be known before you run `slow-seq`, right? I’d like something that would let you dynamically add items without a problem. Specifically, if the result of one API call is that I need to make another API call, will this function allow that second call to be placed on the queue?