# Clojure remove first(or last) element of vector inside ref

Tags: concurrency, clojure, atomic

The thing i need - is simple queue, something, where i can put tasks, and retrieve them one-by-one from workers(without maintaining order of tasks).

I wrote something like this:

```
;; Definition
(def q (ref []))

;; Put
(defn put-in-queue [i]
  (dosync (alter q conj i)))

;; Get
(defn get-from-queue []
  (dosync
    (let [v (peek q)]
      (alter q pop)
      v)))
```

Is it correct solution? (maybe there are also better solutions for this task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is probably to use a `java.util.concurrent` queue, most likely [`java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). `j.u.c` queues are robust, perfectly suited to the task and work in Clojure just fine.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760224/232707) to the [Producer consumer with qualifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760017/producer-consumer-with-qualifications) SO question for a scenario with 5 producers, 2 consumers and a limited-size queue implemented in two ways for comparison: first with `c.l.PersistentQueue`, second with `j.u.c.LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue`, right tool for the job and all that :).

Sample below "borrowed" from [Hidden features of Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493996/hidden-features-of-clojure):

```
user> (-> (clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)
          (conj 1 2 3)
          pop)
(2 3)
```

See [the remainder of that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493996/hidden-features-of-clojure#2495105) for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

as dsm points out, when you need a queue, use a queue, and for times where you really need a vector and want to add things to the end and remove them from the front, `subvec` and `conj` are both O(1) functions on vectors.

```
user> (subvec [1 2 3] 1)
[2 3]
user> (conj [1 2 3] 4)
[1 2 3 4]
user> (-> [] (conj 1 2) (conj 3) (subvec 1))
```

Comment: The question is about multithreaded environment, not just take subvec.

Comment: `clojure.core/subvec` holds on to the underlying vector, so this would prevent all entries from becoming eligible for GC indefinitely. (In contrast, `clojure.core.rrb-vector/subvec` does perform a real slice, discarding entries outside of the given index range.)